What Would Give Skin a "Plastic-y" Texture
I want to describe the skin of a creature that's unnaturally smooth and stretchy, but not completely shiny like actual plastic... More matte, like dry soap. How can I rationalize this kind of skin?
No actual plastic/inorganic material involved. Could be artificial otherwise though.

Ever touched a cephalopod? Smooth, slippery, and stretchy. unnaturally so

When you say "plastic-y" do you mean rubbery? Sufferers of Scleroderma have skin that's sometimes described as a plastic texture, but that's referring to plastic's natural rigidity. It seems like what you really want is rubbery (higher density, matte finish, stretchy).

@JustAnotherUser Ah, the humble cephalopod... What makes them so smooth, slippery, and stretchy?

@JBH Rubbery works just as well... I just chose plastic since rubber is, technically, a naturally occurring material, and "plastic" describes the feeling of it seeming unnatural better.

Hyperelasticity combined with a waterproof secretion.
The hyperelasticity of the skin can be explained through the way it is formed. In normal human skin, there's an implicit structure of connective tissues, various types of collagen in the skin form cross-linkages so as to limit the stretchiness and to provide physical integrity. A mutation, such as with Ehlers–Danlos syndromes (a lesser disadvantageous form) prevents the cross-linkages from restricting stretchiness, leaving only the more stretchy elastic fibers to support the surface tissues (elastin).
The secretion, much like sebum in humans (or lanolin in sheep) forms a protective layer ensuring the water-integrity of the skin.
The creature may well be adapted to an ultra-dry environment. Elephants for example have skin that soaks-up fluids from inside the creature when drinking acting as a reservoir in the days/weeks of being away from water. In their case, the skin is winkled and rough - but in the case of your creature, it's able to stretch every-which way and retain the smooth character.
Alternatively it's adapted to a saline environment - sea-water. It gets its water from the food it eats (much like dolphins do) rather than the sea directly. This means that it is required to store water in its skin much as elephants do, it also needs a waterproof layer of sebum-like substance to prevent direct loss of water by osmosis. The waxy/soapy layer may provide hydrodynamic advantages, reducing drag and allowing for faster swimming at a lower energy-cost (much like the mucilaginous secretions of fish).
Either way, parasites find it more difficult to get a foothold on soapy/waxy skin.
